# Using HTML.DisplayFor to return the value of a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

Visual Studio 2012 MVC4

Hi,

I am currently working on the following class for employee which contains a method for determining the employee's age:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string empID { get; set; }
    public bool isManager { get; set; }
    public string empTel { get; set; }
    public string empEml { get; set; }
    public string empDOB { get; set; }
    public string empBio { get; set; }


    public int empAge()
    {
        DateTime birthdate = DateTime.Parse(empDOB);

        int age = DateTime.Now.Year - birthdate.Year;
        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < birthdate.DayOfYear)
        {
            age = age - 1;
        }

        return age;
    }


    public string empMarketLocation { get; set; }
    public double WeeklyHours { get; set; }


    public Employee()
    {

    }


}




}
```

I initially thought I would be able to display the result of the method in my view withe the following line:

```
   @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => Model.empAge())
```

However, I get the following error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

I am uncertain if I cannot use HTML Display or if I simply have written it wrong. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: what about making `empAge` a property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `empAge` with `Html.DisplayFor` helper method if it's a property instead of a method. Change `empAge` to a property

```
public int empAge
{
    get
    {
        DateTime birthdate = DateTime.Parse(empDOB);

        int age = DateTime.Now.Year - birthdate.Year;
        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < birthdate.DayOfYear)
        {
            age = age - 1;
        }

        return age;
    }
}
```

and change this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => Model.empAge())
```

to this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.empAge)
```

Comment: do not write business logic in view @ekad is right make property in view model